# Reasons for "Failed to lookup views (...) in directory (...)" error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

Hey I'm trying to debug an error that's comming up with rendering a .jade page with node.js and ExpressJS.

The error is: `Error: Failed to lookup view "/workspace/friends" in views directory "C:\Users\Utilizador\Documents\GitHub\QuantBull-Project\views"`.

So what are the reasons for occurring this error. I'm asking this because supposedly it should be working fine, at least it does with the other files...

I created a the following GET listener, located at `controller/workspace.js` to render the file:

```
 /**
   * GET /workspace/friends
   */

  app.get('/workspace/friends', function (req, res) {
    res.render('/workspace/friends', {
      url: '/workspace'
    });
  });
```

and the file called `friends.jade` is located under `views/workspace`.

So I was wondering what can originate this error? Because this situation looks different compared to the other situations with the same error message I found on SO and others...

Comment: I got this error when the path `views/workspace/friends.jade` was invalid. make sure file is present with same names.

Comment: @Mritunjay That's the strange part. The file is there with the same name...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured out, problem is here.

use below

```
res.render('workspace/friends')
```

instead of

```
 res.render('/workspace/friends')
```

When you say `res.render('somefolder/file)` so it searches in `views/someolder/file`. Because you are saying `res.render('/somefolder/somefile)` so it should be getting confused with `/`.

Comment: Damn it! I lost one whole day because of this `/`! Thank you very much! The best Birthday present I could get today! :-P